# iPhone Large Matrix Multiplication on GPU

Tags: iphone, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, gpu

I've designed a learning AI for use in a iPad game but its prototype is written in matlab. I need to perform several actions such as: (capital denotes matrix)

```
A = B > c;
A = B * C;
A = B' * C;
A = B .* C;
A = B - C;
```

And some of my matrices are large (2601 x 100). Running these operations on a GPU could significantly improve the performance of this operation. Is there a Linear Algebra library more appropriate than Accelerate's BLAS? BLAS only supports up to 4x4 matrices.

Comment: After a few days of searching I found ViennaCL. It performs linear algebra on the gpu. I don't know how well it works on the iPad though. I'll do some benchmarking when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had pretty good results in a former project using the (open source) [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library.

- It's a C++ template library containing header files only, but this is no problem as you can write your interfaces either in plain C or Objective-C++ (.mm).
- Its code is heavily optimised for armv7.
- The LGPL3 licensing model should be a pretty good choice for releasing apps on the app-store without interfering with Apple's TOS.